# ERROR in EACCES: permission denied, open '/home...//node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i am always having this error while runing my reactjs app, please i need your help. permission denied error. sudo permission is not solving the  bug.I can't figure out what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A.Run your code editor in `Admin mode` (with admin permissions)

B.Delete your `node_modules`

C.`npm install` in your console

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem every time I forgot to type `sudo`.

just add `sudo` at the start of your command,
if you use `yarn` and the `ubuntu` os, start your app like  this:

`sudo yarn start`